# Why rm command in Linux can delete file/dir in seconds while delete in FTP is really slow

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

Recently I created some dir which contains a lot of files and subdir by mistake. And then I tried to delete the dir through my FTP software (FileZilla), but it's really slow, like you can see it cost 2/3 seconds to delete each file.

So I stopped it and tried that through SSH and use `rm -rf` command, then the target directory was deleted just in a second.

My question is why it's so slow on FTP while fast on SSH?

Much thanks!

Comment: Once you've authenticated via ssh, you're using a Unix bash shell. OS operations are going to be fast in execution. The only delay you'd experience would be the time it takes to send your `rm -rf` command to the remote machine. That said, I'm not sure why FileZilla would take longer. It might be sending each file delete operation one at a time. 
Have you tried using sftp over command line (see sftp's `rmdir` command)?

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE SFTP is the same as FTP, in this respect. There's no "delete tree" command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete a directory tree, you have to iterate it, retrieve lists of all files and subdirectories, and delete them one by one.

- When you use the *remote* `rm -rf` command, it has a direct access to the file system, so it is relatively quick.
- While the FTP client has to retrieve the file lists (what involves couple of FTP command exchanges, opening data channel, listing transfer, etc) and then it has to delete the files one by one. Each delete involves sending the FTP command, waiting for the response. So it takes long.

There's no "delete whole tree" command in FTP protocol that would be an equivalent of the `rm -rf` command executed on the remote shell.

Comment: THX! That make sense, because I can see the FTP refresh (the page refresh periodically) itself when it's doing the delete work.